# Laravel inverse relation

Tags: php, sql, laravel, controller

So i have two tables:

```
Schema::create('goods', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('amount');
            $table->integer('shop_id');
            $table->timestamp('onPurchase');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('shops', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('adress')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I want to print list of all goods and add name of the shop to every line of the good. When route opens this function runs:

```
function toBuy(){
        $good = Good::all();
        $data ['good'] = $good;
        return view('tobuy', $data);
    }
```

Blade:

```
@foreach ($good as $ginfo)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$ginfo->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$ginfo->amount}}</td>
                    <td>
                    @foreach ($ginfo->shop as $shop)
                        {{$shop->name}}
                    @endforeach
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <a href="{{ route ('goodDelete', $ginfo->id) }}" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

So how do i form a proper relationship using models Good and Shop and print what i need. Tried many ways and failed. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `Good` model

```
public function shop()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Shop');
}
```

Controller code

```
public function toBuy()
{
    $goods = Good::with('shop')->get();

    return view('tobuy')->with(['goods' => $goods]);
}
```

View code

```
@foreach ($goods as $good)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $good->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $good->amount }}</td>
        <td>{{ $good->shop->name }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ route ('goodDelete', $good->id) }}" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I get: BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2451:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()

Comment: @Benua sorry about that, updated. Forgot to replace the `all()` with `get()`